# Last view superimposed on current view when double-back navigating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, drawing

I do the following navigation pattern:

1. Navigate into the app (and it's main view)
2. Go into a detail view that fetches something from a REST server (that is - it shows a progress indicator for a few seconds)
3. While progress indicator still is shown, I click the back-button twice in quick succession (easy to do by mistake)
4. The app returns to the main view, but with the content of the detail view **superimposed** on it.

A screenshot of the resulting mess is shown below.

This was recreated both on a Nokia Lumia 800 and HTC Titan.

First of all - what the h..? And is there anything I could have done to make this happen?

There is no exceptions (or anything else) shown in the output. The only thing happening in the `OnNavigatedFrom()` method of the detail view is nulling out the background image (for memory reasons). It happens in other views as well.

My idea is that the draw method on both views are called on different threads, leaving only the main view to be responsive.

Any idea as to what has happened here, and how I can fix this bug?

[image: A screenshot of what has happened]

Comment: exactly the same thing happened to me. Are you by any chance using the Transition frame from the Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit?

Comment: I am. :-) Did that have anything to do with this situation?

Comment: It may have, because the only time I experienced this exact issue was when I used the transition. Could you try removing it and then try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: That did fix it somewhat, but then again, I would still like to have my transitions and use them too. Is there any way I could do this while still keeping my transitions?

Comment: I think it's a bug of some kind, but I am unaware of the way to fix or avoid it... (except for not using the transition frame at all)
You could try asking at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic Perhaps you could disable the back button key press while still loading (I am not sure if this will pass the certification). Or at least prompt user with messagebox to tell him that the page is still loading and ask if he's sure that he wants to do it (may stop him from tapping back twice)

Comment: Thanks man. Write up some kind of answer for this, and I'll accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issue happened to me when using TransitionFrame from Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit. Using transitions when navigating from page to page can cause this if the user taps on back button once or twice while the transition/navigation is in progress.

I believe it's a bug, but couldn't find it reported at the official [CodePlex site of the toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic), therefore I don't know about any reliable solution or workaround except trying to handle the back button press on the page that's causing issues. In other words, catching the back button/key press and either disabling it (I'm not sure that this would pass certification!), or simply prompting user with a MessageBox that the page is still loading and if they are sure that they want to navigate back, might work for you.
Other solution I can think of is that you avoid using TransitionFrame, but that's not really a solution, right? :)